# Is there a symbol that means "chapter"?

Tags: symbols

Is there a symbol that means "chapter" the way `\S` means "section"? I'm not sure what it might look like -- maybe a "C" with a circle in the middle?

Comment: Actually `\S` rather means `paragraph`, but this may differ from language to language or country to country. On the other hand:   U+00A7 „Section sign“

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In English it means section. There's a different symbol for paragraphs, I think. (Not sure if it only means end of paragraph or new paragraph rather than referring to one, though.) Nothing for chapter that I know of. Just `ch.` or `chap.` as abbreviations.

Comment: This question is really off-topic here. If you had a symbol you wanted to draw, it would be on-topic. But whether there is a symbol for X in a particular language and/or discipline, or which symbol should be used etc. - those are not questions for this site.

Comment: @cfr OK fair enough. I am pretty sure there is no "official" symbol for chapter, but I guess I thought some LaTeXer might make a suggestion of a LaTeX symbol that s/he tends to use for that purpose.

Comment: I use `p.` or `ch.` depending on language. I'd expect these to be understood. If I invented a symbol for chapters, I'd expect nobody to know what I meant.

Comment: In medieval Latin legal texts (which also regularly use '¶' and '§'), the common abbreviation was simply 'c.' or 'cap.' (for 'capitulum'; also for 'canon', which means 'rule' [in this context]). These conventions were continued in the first centuries of print.